# How to debug Arduino Duemilanove Boards using Atmel Studio Version.6.2

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-debugging, arduino-ide, atmelstudio

I am using Arduino Duemilanove and I have followed the tutorial from this link http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/ inoredr to use flash the program from *Atmel Studio 6.2* , hence I was able to create and flash a sample program .

But the problem is , How can I debug the program by setting break-points, Do I need to use any debugger like STK500 to debug

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the problem is , How can I debug the program by setting
>   break-points, Do I need to use any debugger like STK500 to debug?

The STK500 is a *programmer* not a *debugger*.

You need a MKII, AVR Dragon or JTAG ICE in order to be able to debug using the DebugWire protocol.

Don't forget to setup the `OCD` bit in the fuses, though I guess Atmel Studio should do it for you.